# I can´t update screen with a command in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a ImageButton that when I click it, make visible other buttons. By default, the other ImageButtons are invisible.

I know I must refresh the screen but I don't know how to do it. I tried using "INotifyPropertyChanged" but it doesn't  work.

MainPage.xaml:

[MainPage.xaml (I can´t paste the code, I don't know why)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVfkb.png)

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public string ButtonColor { get; set; }
    
    public string IsVisible2 { get; set; }

    public string Website { get; set; }
   // public Command<string> OpenAppCommand { get; set; }

    public Command OpenAppCommand { get; }
    public Command OpenFloating { get; }



    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenAppCommand = new Command(launcWeb);
        OpenFloating = new Command(openFloatingButton);

        IsVisible2 = "false";          
        ImageSource = "share256white.png";
        ButtonColor = "red";
    }


    
    public void launcWeb()
    {
        Website = "https://facebook.com";
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(Website));
    }

   //===============================
    
    Boolean firstStart = true;
    Boolean nextClick = true;

    public void openFloatingButton()
    {

        
        if (firstStart)
        {

            IsVisible2 = "true";
            firstStart = false;


        }
        else
        {


            if (nextClick)
            {

                IsVisible2 = "false";
                nextClick = false;

            }
            else
            {

                IsVisible2 = "true";
                nextClick = true;

            }



        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your `IsVisible2` property should be a `bool`

e.g.

```
public bool IsVisible2 { get; set; }
```

Secondly there is no evidence of your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation which is likely why it won't work. Documentation on how to implement it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1)

You need to implement that interface on your `ViewModel` class.

Something like:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isVisible2;

    public bool IsVisible2
    {
        get => isVisible2;
        set
        {
            isVisible2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
}
```